# HTML-escaping replacement fields when using str.format() in Python

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

I am using the string [`.format()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) function to format my strings with keyword arguments.  I pass in some basic objects to the strings and use attributes of these objects in the strings.  For example:

```
"Hello, {user.first_name}!".format(user=my_user)
```

These strings may be used in HTML e-mails, so the replacement fields should be HTML-escaped (using `django.utils.html.escape`).

What is the best way to use an escape function for string replacement fields when formatting a string?  If this is not reasonably possible, what is an appropriate alternative to string formatting?  My strings are being stored in a database and modified through the Django admin interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the question is why you are using format to begin with.  Aren't you going to push this to a template?  I mean, if you escape something in your template (using a template tag) you're pretty much just passing a string through this escape function.

Maybe this isn't what you're looking for but would't you just do,

```
"Hello, {user.first_name}!".format(user=django.utils.html.escape(my_user))
```

?

If you wanted to escape all your arguments and you were sure they would be
strings,

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    for key,val in kwargs.iteritems():
        kwargs[key] = django.utils.html.escape(val)

    ...
```

You could also probably do something a little more crazy like,

```
def foo(**kwargs):
    kwargs = dict((key, val) for key,val in izip(kwargs.iterkeys(), \
    map(django.utils.htmls.escape, kwargs.itervalues())))

    # OR if you use Python 3
    kwargs = {key:django.utils.htmls.escape(val) for key, val in kwargs.items()}
```

if you wanted stuff to get CRAZY!

Comment: I am actually using `.format()` in lieu of templates currently (these are used for formatting e-mails).  The kwargs escape approach also won't work for my case because it would escape the arguments themselves (transforming them into strings) so expressions like `{user.first_name}` would not work because `user` would be a string.

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary solution before I move to using Django templates, I subclassed `string.Formatter` as mentioned in the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/string.html#string-formatting).

```
import string
from django.utils.html import escape

class EscapingFormatter(string.Formatter):
    def format_field(self, value, format_spec):
        return escape(super(EscapingFormatter, self).format_field(value, format_spec))

formatter = EscapingFormatter()
formatter.format("Hello, {user.first_name}!", user=my_user)
```

This solution should work outside of Django as well (the `escape` function will obviously need to be replaced though).